# Inline fields on node edit form

Tags: 7, display-suite

I managed to get fields inline on node display, but cant find a module to help me do it on node input. I am mostly using DS, field collection and field group (field gruop has this option but only for display, not for edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Display processors are not used when rendering the node form. It's a completely different process. I'm not aware of any contrib modules that will help you accomplish this. However you can write your own.

You need to start by creating a very simple custom module with just a .info, a .module and a .css file. You can find lots of tutorials online.

Then you want to write that CSS to make your particular form fields inline and attach the css to the form using [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). If you named your module "hook" the code would look like this (This code goes in your hook.module file):

```
// Replace hook with name of module and yourcontenttype
// with machine name of your content type
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'yourcontenttype_node_form') {
    $form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'hook') . '/hook.css';
  }
}
```

After that enable the module, clear all caches and it should be including the new CSS in the admin form.

Comment: Thanks. If you could please point of few tutorials how to start on this would be great. I dont know much about coding (css i understand a bit), but with mentioned modules above i was able to do whatever i want for displaying nodes, even for editing node forms there are many nice options that made edit forms look exaclly as i want, but this specific feature is missing in all of them.

Comment: This would be a good place to start: https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390

Comment: Isn't a '/' missing at the beginning of the .css filename: `'/hook.ccs';`?